# Updating Meta Title in Magento via PHP script causes unwanted events

Tags: magento, m2e-pro

On our Magento 1.5.0.1 I wrote a PHP script to update all of our product meta titles to be based on the name and SKU of each product. The script is run by calling PHP via SSH.

After running the script I noticed in our M2E Pro (the eBay syncing module) that every single product appears to have become disabled.

[image: Magento Screenshot]

Looking at the actual products they aren't disabled, so it appears my script is somehow faking the event.

Out of our 3,000+ products, though, one of them was disabled and subsequently M2E Pro removed the listing from eBay.

Here is my script:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
define('MAGENTO', "/home/discount/public_html");
require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('meta_title');

$total = count($products);
$count = 1;

foreach ($products as $product)
{
    $mt = sprintf("%s [%s]", $product->getName(), $product->getSku());
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    if ($product->getMetaTitle() != $mt)
    {
        $percent = $count / $total;
        echo $sku." ".$percent."\n";
        $product->setMetaTitle($mt);
        $product->save();
    }
}
?>
```

I'd like to know what I need to do to my script to make it correctly update the meta title without causing odd events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stab in the dark here, but it's a good chance the M2E extension has an event listener setup for model/product saves, and in that event listener does things depending on product state.

By itself this isn't a problem, but when you load an EAV model via its collection it loads the bare minimum of attributes.  Since you haven't explicitly loaded product status via `addAttributeToSelect` this may be confusing the M2E extension.  Trying adding the status attribute.  If that doesn't work try `addAttributeToSelect('*')` — M2E may be checking other attributes as well to decide when to pull things.

Finally, when you load an EAV model via a collection their `afterLoad` isn't called.  It's possible the M2E extension (naively) assumes something that happens in `afterLoad` will have happened, so you may want to call it explicitly for each product.

```
$product->afterLoad();
```

Short of that, you'll need to reverse engineer M2E to the point in the code where it's doing it's above logging and determine why it thinks it needs to disable a product.  Since this is a commercial extension, I'd reach out to the developers. If you pay for something you deserve some level of support.

Comment: Super answer. The `addAttributeToSelect('*')` did the trick. The `afterLoad` caused an unknown method exception, but it wasn't needed. Cheers.

Comment: @Enigmativity Moot at this point, but you call afterLoad on the individual models, not on the collection.

Comment: I did do the call on the individual product inside the foreach loop. Not sure why it didn't work then...

Comment: @Enigmativity  I'd be curious at the exact error message you got.  afterLoad **is** method on the catalog/product object.

Comment: This is the error I got: "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product::afterLoad() in /home/discount/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 280".

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks, that's a bug for sure — confirmed here.  A model's afterLoad calls the resource's after load, and the EAV resources don't look like they have an after load in the current version(s) of Magento.

Comment: Thanks, but now I feel worried. Is this a problem or not? Is this just another reason to upgrade to 1.7?

Comment: It's a bug in the most recent versions of Magento as well, upgrading won't fix it.  http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=13984

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//increase the max execution time
@ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
//memory_limit
@ini_set('memory_limit', -1);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// Start Despaly All Product Meta Title And Description
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                         ->getCollection()
                         // magic is prepared here..
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         // then the magic happens here:
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('level', array('eq'=>4))
                         ->load();
    if (count($categories) > 0):

        foreach($categories as $category):

            $catId = $category->getId();
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
            $resource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category');
            //if($catId==1465):  //If Update Specific category Value by Id
                $CategoryName = $category->getName(); 
                $metaTitle = "Buy ".$CategoryName." Test Title";
                $metaDescription = "Shop your favourite ".$CategoryName." Test Description";

                $category->setData('meta_title', $metaTitle);
                $resource->saveAttribute($category, 'meta_title');
                $category->setData('meta_description', $metaDescription);
                $resource->saveAttribute($category, 'meta_description');

                $check = $category->getMetaTitle();
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($catId);
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($check);
                echo "\n";
            //endif; 

        endforeach;
     else: echo "No Results";
    endif;

?>
```

Comment: This code also can be use for update category attribute value like (Meta Title value, Meta description Value) by script run from root Directory.